# React gives an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < when route is more than one section

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to access route like `http://localhost:3000/add/group` but it gives this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in `<!DOCTYPE html>` and other links are working properly.

This is my code:

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, path: path, ...rest }) => (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        path={path}
        render={props =>
        window.Auth.isAuthenticated() ? (
            <Layout>
            <Component {...props} />
            </Layout>
        ) : (
            <Redirect
            to={{
                pathname: "/",
                state: { from: props.location }
            }}
            />
        )
        }
    />
    );

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
     <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute path="/add/h" component={AddGroup} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
    </Provider>,
app);
```

layout component in the code refers to my layout pages

private component is for restricting user from some pages

Thanks.

Comment: Is it normal to have `/add/h` vs `/add/group` ?

Comment: sorry, this is writing mistake